# Ruby on Rails can use remote-true without helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can I use remote->true without helper?and set its interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Rails UJS**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs)

[`remote: true`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers) is nothing more than a way to set a `data` attribute in your DOM elements:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/articles" class="new_article" data-remote="true" id="new_article" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

It basically calls the [Rails UJS "driver"](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs), which is nothing more than a way to call standardized javascript functionality out of scope of the typical application setup.

You can [see the UJS "ajax" driver source here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L92)

---

**Integration**

Your question is regarding whether you need the "helpers" to invoke this technology, the short answer is "yes".

The Rails UJS driver is only going to work if you have an element which *submits*. The way that JS works is to "bind" events to elements, which then proceeds to fire the bound function if you trigger that event.

In the case of "typical" JS (JQuery), you'll be able to set up an Ajax request by the following:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".your_button", function(){
   $.ajax({
      ...
   });
});
```

By the way, the Rails UJS *basically* does this:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-remote]", function(){
    $.ajax({
        ....
    });
});
```

Now, the most important thing to note here is how both of these implementations bind your "click" / "submit" event to an ajax call. This is the basis of Javascript - any time you want to invoke the action, you have to bind to an event

---

**Map**

In respect to your question, the answer is that you will be best using your own `ajax` call unless you have a *clear* "action" to be called. What this means if you want to use something like [long-polling](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery), you'll have to call `ajax` yourself.

If you want to create a form, link or another element which will either be *clicked*, or be *submitted*, you'll be able to call the Rails UJS `remote: true` method.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: use the link generating helper like:

```
<%= link_to 'Anywhere', anywhere_path, remote: true %>
```

which generates the correct HTML markup for you. Sure you don't need the helper, but you want to use it. ;)
Otherwise you would write this yourself:

```
<a href="<%= anywhere_path %>" data-remote="true">Anywhere</a>
```

Comment: So I need this link_to to enable my remote ajax even if I dont need it?works as a bridge?

Comment: No you do not need it. But you want it. One reason why you want it, it saves you from nasty HTML/Ruby mixed markup hassle. Btw. it's cleaner and will ALWAYS generate valid HTML. Please mark answer as solved, if it answered your question.